# How to run a nested RemoteAction query to update original object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting, remote-action

In the below function I'm trying to update the first result object with the count of matches found in the second query.  Problem appears to be that I can't update result[i] within the second query, and that domainResult isn't accessible after the second query is finished.  Using other global variables doesn't work either - even with a nested loop in the second query.  Ideas?

```
function loadLeads() {
var tststring = 'SELECT Id, Email, Email_Domain__c, FROM Lead WHERE Email LIKE \'someperson@somedomain.com\'';

Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.LeadSearchJS.findLeads}', tststring,
    function(result, event) {
        if(event.status)
            {
            console.log('result', result);
            console.log('event', event);
            for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                var id = result[i].Id;
                var emailDomain = result[i].Email_Domain__c;
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.LeadSearchJS.findMatch}', emailDomain,
                    function(domainResult, domainEvent) {
                    if(domainEvent.status)
                    {
                        matchDomainLength = 0;
                        console.log('matchDomainLength2',matchDomainLength);
                        console.log('domainresult', domainResult);
                        //console.log('domainevent', domainEvent);
                        //now do something with each result.  result[i] is the original main email, domainresult is the matches by email domain
                        for (var a=0;a<domainResult.length; a++) {
                            //here we are looping through each email domain match for the original email
                            matchDomainLength = matchDomainLength + 1;
                            console.log('counting mdl', matchDomainLength);
                            // CAN'T ACCESS THE VARIABLE i IN HERE - RESULT[i].___ doesn't work
                            }
                    } //end if
                });//end of second remote action
                console.log('matchDomainLength3',matchDomainLength);
                // console.log('matchDomainLength4',domainResult.Length); (this doesn't work - domainResult appears to be released by now)
                result[i].DomainMatches = matchDomainLength;  //MATCHDOMAINLENGTH IS BACK TO 0
            }
        }

});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why the apex method `findLeads()` cannot just call `findMatch()`.

It's not a good idea to make remote method calls in a for loop either. It's best to capture the js environment once. Do everything you need on the server and send back a success/failure message and any JSON data you might need.

Comment: Absolutely should be able to return one JSON object!